# adding barriers in arcgis sdk is generating the same path

Tags: android, arcgis

I have a program which gives me this route when I point at the to the two red markers[image]

I wanted to make that road not available so that I can get an alternate path, so I added this code to create a barrier on that road
            `Polygon po=new Polygon();
            Point p1=new Point(4102363.9071817156,857772.619643);
            Point p2=new Point(4102416.5557467686,857799.2401230272);
            Point p3=new Point(4102436.1589281,857744.31787604);
            po.startPath(p1);
            po.lineTo(p2);
            po.lineTo(p3);
            Graphic ba_gr=new Graphic(po,null);
            NAFeaturesAsFeature na=new NAFeaturesAsFeature();
            na.addFeature(ba_gr);
            params.setPolygonBarriers(na);`
 but still I am getting the same path, so can anyone tell me where I made the mistake or if there is another way to create a barrier?
parms is my RouteParameters and the polygon is at this position.[image]

Comment: I would be glad if anyone could even give me a link on which I could learn more about setting up barriers with examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your NAfeature spital reference must be the same as ur mapview spital reference.
so try na.setspitalreference(mapview.getspitalreference)